# Windows cmd, file rename and rearange

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm a biologist, and sometimes I have to work with quite a lot of files, which are arranged not in an optimal way by someone.

Can you give me a tip on the following task?
There are folders

```
D:\.......\folder1\subfolder(1....)\subsubfolder(1.....)  \SOMEtext_exactword(1.....)
```

(the last one are files without extension)

Can I create in windows cmd something like

```
D:\.......\folderEXACTWORD1\(subfolder1_subsubfolder1_SOMEtext_exactword1,
subfolder2_subsubfolder2_SOMEtext_exactword1,  
subfolder3_subsubfolder3_SOMEtext_exactword1)
```

(the last one are files without extension again)

Meaning to find all files, containing "string" in their name in few sub folders, copy them into the specific folder and rename them, so they contain their parent file location in their name now.

I guess there should be a way to do it in a linux, though I am not a linux user and not a good (not at all actually) coder myself. Though I can handle some work, so I would be happy if someone can give me a tip whats the easiest way to do what I want. Or what can I search - I tried to search, but maybe I am missing some right words to look for.

Comment: So in short you want to search for files containing `string` move them to a folder and rename them to the folder name they came from?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but here is more or less something that does this, you have to still define a few more items to make sure your find the correct files in locations and move them accordingly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mydir="D:\somedir\somedir\someotherdir\

for %%a in (%mydir%) do set "name=%%~nxa"
echo %name%
for /r %%i in (*string*) do (set "file=%%i"
 echo move "!file!" "C:\somedir\!name!")
 )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score -2):

Well. Someone elsewhere has given me advice and it worked. In total commander, you can do it with multi-rename tool and flags [P] and [G] which will allow you to add parent and grandparent directory name.

Well. I guess there is nothing wrong with having this topic with answer from myself, but I will be ok if it is deleted :)
Though I will be still interested if it can be done from cmd, just out of curiosity.